# Nginx as a proxy to Apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx

My project contains all files whose extensions are either .php, .js and .css .. No .html is there.. I have set up Nginx using port 80 and Apache using port 8080 in localhost.. Nginx is said to handle the static things very fast and pass the php to Apache.. So since my project does not have any .html files Nginx is supposed to bypass everything to Apache.. So how is Nginx helping here? And if not, then what should I do to utilize Nginx.?

Is it possible to see the current running stats of Apache's and Nginx's.?

Sorry, if these questions seems to be of amateur type but I am just a fresh mint here..and I need help here...

Comment: Do you mean Tomcat is running at 8080?

Comment: no it's Xampp which is running at 8080

Comment: Oh, if you are proxying Nginx to a regular Apache webserver you proably don't want to do that unless you are using nginx for loadbalancing or what not.  Typically you replace apache with nginx, and do proxy passes into application servers like Tomcat, Node, etc.

Comment: nginx could serve js and css files, if they are static.

Comment: Then when should I use Nginx? and what is an irregular Apache webserver? Please elaborate....

Comment: among js there are many ajax calls.. and there is a longpolling script executed at php side.. So nginx is doing nothing here??

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is surely responsible here to show the css and js files which are probably not ajax like jquery.min.js which are static quickly..And if you consider caching the contents like image and all, Nginx will serve a purpose here...

You said that many of the js you have used are ajax . So why not show the .html pages in the website and pull the dynamic data from other php pages to the html page you are showing via ajax.. In that case Nginx will serve a purpose as well...

Here is a tool which you can use to see the stats... Check this out.
[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/index.php)

I'm not an expert..But I tried my best to answer..Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I recall one more reason to use nginx. In prevents "slow client attack" to Apache. It could be not an attack per se, but many valid client with slow connection.

Comment: slow client attack?? what does that mean??